# Mojave - Some Apps Lose Internet Connectivity

Tags: network, wifi, mojave

**Scenario**

I recently installed Mojave and I've noticed that after an undetermined amount of time that many apps complain of not having a connection to the internet eg Mac Mail and Spotify. Meanwhile chrome works the entire time.

**Tested Solutions**

Turn off WiFi, reconnect WiFi

**Current Solution**

Restart Computer

## Question

Why is this happening? Is there any way around it other that completely restarting my computer?

Comment: restart the wifi

Comment: @Buscar웃 On 10.12 I would sometimes get connectivity issues so I would restart wifi and connectivity would come back. With 10.14 however, restarting the wifi doesn't change anything. I'm sure the issue with 10.14 that I'm experiencing is OS software related.

Comment: Restarting WiFi is a slow process, after turning it Off wait at least 10 seconds before turning it On.

Comment: @Buscar웃 No luck. The good news is that I haven't seen this issue happen in quite some times. Maybe it's been hot-fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue like that, my solution  was restart the mac. Maybe, it will be solved by apple on the next updates.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's about all we can do for now. I know apple has a [bug reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) and I'm sure a number of developers have already reported this seeing as how xcode 10 / ios 12 dev requires mojave.